# convert element sizes from PSD to HTML with responsive design

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

I have to convert a PSD file to an HTML5 with responsive design.
It's the first time I do it I would like some clear orientation.

When i extract the CSS files from the PSD I see strange things like all element are in position=absolute, which seems quite dummy. I assume I have to change it according to the new HTML?

How to make it responsive to different screen widhts and heights as well as mobile? If I directly embed to Bootstrap elements is supposed to do that?

should I calculate from the PSD the relative sizes of each element (relative to the height and widht of the PSD file) and convert to %? (ex: body of the PSD file 100px, 1 element in PSD file 50px->CSS of the element1 in HTML 50%)

Comment: PSD is Photoshop native format. What tool are you using to extract CSS from a PSD?

Comment: Photoshop itself... left bottom over the layer and 'copy CSS'

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way to do this is to [slice the PSD](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/slice-and-dice-that-psd/) and extract only those elements that **need** to be images. Then create your HTML and CSS.

If you've never created a responsive site before, I recommend checking out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). You might decide to use one of those frameworks or not, but just looking at them and playing with the examples will give you a good idea of how responsive websites work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use twitter bootstrap frame work for PSD to responsive html site build that would be fine, cause all are there with frame work, no need to make any device level calculation.

You can download twitter bootstrap files here, http://getbootstrap.com

HTML Developer @ http://www.psddesigntohtml.com

Hope its help, thanks!